# border:2px solid red VS border:2px red solid

Tags: css

Are both method valid? both works same.

```
border:2px solid red;
```

and

```
border:2px red solid;
```

Comment: You're lucky if you're building a site and this is all you get to worry about :D

Comment: @alex - I'm not worry, just asking for knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands) (the official spec) says that the value for the `border` shorthand property is this:

```
<line-width> || <line-style> || <color>
```

So it specifies that the order you should use is width, style, color. In other words, `border: 2px solid red;` from your example.

The other method is technically "undefined", but browsers usually display it correctly because there is no confusion between the style and colour values; there is currently no colour called "solid" or "dashed". Stick with the official method anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I always do `border: 2px solid red` but that's my personal choice.

It is just short hand for

```
element {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It mostly works the same, but if you want to be safe use this order when specifying a shorthand for border

```
border-width
border-style
border-color
```

so

```
border:2px solid red;
```

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp - This is a good site to use as reference for issues like this.

Comment: so if anyone is using `border:2px red solid;` should i suggest him to not to use this order?

Comment: :) That's is up to you. I personally would suggest following the standard.